# Vector rearrangement for 2 objects getting closer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, vectors

I'm not good with vectors, forgive me for my question.

[image]

From the above image, the book deduces the following:

[image]

I'm trying to see how $\Delta r_2 - \Delta r_1 = r_f - r_i$. I want to forget the right side and calculate left side first and follow the concrete example.

m2's initial position is (7,6) and moves to (4.7), while m1's initial position is (2,2) and moves to (3,1). To calculate $\Delta r_2$, I do: (7,6) - (4,7) which is 3,-1 which is in magnitude to be $\sqrt{10}$. $\Delta r_1$ is (2,2) - (3,1) = -1,1 which is $\sqrt{2}$, so on the left side we got: $\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2}$.

On the right side, I'm calculating $r_f - r_i$. $r_f = (4,7) - (3,1) = 1,6 = \sqrt{37}$ and $r_i$ = (7,6) - (2,2) = (5,4) = $\sqrt{41}$.

Now I get $\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{41} - \sqrt{37}$ and this doesn't hold true. Where am I making a mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation

$\Delta \vec r_2 - \Delta \vec r_1 = \vec r_f - \vec r_i$

is a *vector* equation, but you are trying to interpret each term in the equation as if it were a scalar.

In your example,

$\Delta \vec r_2 = (4,7) - (7,6) = (-3,1)
\\ \Delta \vec r_1 = (3,1) - (2,2) = (1,-1)
\\ \Rightarrow \Delta \vec r_2 - \Delta \vec r_1 = (-3,1) - (1,-11) = (-4,2)$

and

$\vec r_f = (4,7) - (3,1) = (1,6)
\\ \vec r_i = (7,6) - (2,2) = (5,4)
\\ \Rightarrow \vec r_f - \vec r_i = (1,6) - (5,4) = (-4, 2)$

The reason is simply that each side of the original equation is a re-arrangement of $(4,7) -(3,1) - (7,6) + (2,2)$.

If you want to equate magnitudes of vectors, you need to take the magnitude of the whole of the right hand side (which is different from taking the magnitudes of its individual terms) and equate that to the magnitude of the whole left hand side, so you have

$|\Delta \vec r_2 - \Delta \vec r_1| = |\vec r_f - \vec r_i| = \sqrt{4^2+2^2} = \sqrt{20} = 2 \sqrt 5$

Comment: Great answer. Last question if you wouldn't mind. could you tell which vector is $r_{2f}$ and $r_{1f}$ ? can't imagine it on the image

Comment: I can't imagine how would I draw them on the image

Comment: @ZazaOrji $\vec r_{2f}$ and $\vec r_{1f}$ are the final positions of $m_2$ and $m_1$. In your example these are the vectors $(4,7)$ and $(3,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're doing wrong is that in general for two vectors $a$ and $b$, the magnitude of $a+b$ is not the sum of the magnitudes of $a$ and $b$. What you should be doing is $$||\Delta r_2-\Delta r_1||=\sqrt{(\Delta r_2)^2+(\Delta r_1)^2-2\Delta r_2 \cdot\Delta r_1}$$ where the $\cdot$ denotes the dot product. So you have to take into acount the angle between the two displacements to get the correct magnitude.

**EDIT:** I'll give you an example. Let $a=(3,4)$ and $b=(0,1)$. Then, $a-b=(3,3)$. The magnitude of $a-b$ is $\sqrt{18}$, but the magnitude of $a$ and $b$ is $5$ and $1$ respectively. That's because the magnitude of $a-b$ is not the "signed length" of the "path" traced out by $a-b$, but the vector which unites $b$ to $a$

Comment: and where does 2Δ2⋅Δ1 come from then. ?

Comment: In general, the book does it with vectors, but I'm just using magnitudes of it, otherwise, what else Δ2−Δ1 means ? they're both completely different vectors, why can't I just calculate Δ2 separately, then Δ1 separately and do the minus then ? confusing

Comment: @ZazaOrji The term $2\Delta  \vec r_2. \Delta \vec r_1$ is non-zero because $\Delta \vec r_2$ and $\Delta \vec r_1$ are not perpendicular.

Comment: I don't understand why i need this, I calculated Δ2 and Δ1 separately and then did the substraction.  what's wrong with this

Comment: @ZazaOrji The $\Delta r_2-\Delta r_1$ means the vector difference in the initial and final relative positions of the two masses. The problem is that if you calculate the magnitudes separately, and subtract them, that doesn't represent the magnitude  of $\Delta r_2-\Delta r_1$

Answer (score 0):

You may well find it easier to sketch a vector diagram for your situation.

[image]

$\vec {AB} + \vec{BD}+ \vec{DC}+ \vec {CA}=\vec 0 \Rightarrow \Delta\vec r_2 -\vec r_{\rm f} -\Delta\vec r_1+ \vec r_{\rm f}\Rightarrow \Delta\vec r_2 - \Delta\vec r_1 = \vec r_{\rm f} - \vec r_{\rm i}$

Remembering that you are dealing with vectors resolve each of the vectors into an $x$ and $y$ component and add the appropriate components together.
This will be easy to do if you have sketched a vector diagram.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the diagram. How is x/y axis drawn ? why using origin ?

Comment: I think $r_{2i}$ and $r_{2f}$ are not x and y components of $\Delta r_2$.